# Would a shed at the side of my house expose it to a risk of damp?

Tags: shed, damp-proof-course, locating

We're looking to maximise some garden/patio space by relocating our bike storage to a new shed at the side of our property. (See attached picture- apologies for the amateur editing!)

The shed will sit close to the side wall of our house, and will have a roof on a single angle, highest where it meets the house and angled down.

I was wondering if I needed to consider any potential damp issues for the house when locating the shed there, and what mitigating actions I could take. Presumably, adding some flashing at the point where the shed is closest to the house to direct the water is a good start.

Thanks all.[image: house side shed location]

Comment: wouldn't the shed roof move more water away from the house than it is right now?

Comment: If you can leave a little space behind and underneath for air movement should be okay.

Comment: Flashing seems like a good thing but the problem is that flashing should be tucked under your exterior siding or weather-proofed exterior. You can't do that very easily and I doubt you'd gain much. As suggested above I'd just leave some clearance for air circulation. BTW - not much room there. I assume the fence comes down and might be an issue with vehicle traffic if that's a right-of-way.

Comment: @honeydo thanks. Yeah,  the boundary fence will come down.  It's an access drive to parking spaces with very low volume & slow traffic.  I'll be checking with neighbours first,  but oughtn't be a problem.